# How to restart network interface in Debian based linux without being restarting whole system?

Tags: embedded-linux

I am making changes in **/etc/network/interfaces file** static ip addresses.Then after I am restarting network using **/etc/init.d/networking restart** command.By using this command some times the whole system get restarted.What is a proper way to restart network without being restarting whole system.

Comment: restart should restart the network interface, how come it reboots the system, are you sure? perhaps try stop and start to debug what happens in your system.

Comment: Either you can try `ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: It totally depends on the service which takes care of network in your machine. For example if systemd's "networkd" taking care of network then you can try "systemctl restart systemd-networkd". If it is NetworkManager, then you can try restarting NetworkManager. Under systemd platform, you can use "systemctl restart NetworkManager" for that. In any case, system doesn't needs to rebooted.

Comment: I use "ifdown eth0" and "ifup eth0" on Ubuntu.  Of course you would need to replace eth0 with the name of the interface you are trying to restart.

Comment: Yes it works for me .Now whole system is not restarting.@Marker

Comment: Using this ifdown and ifup command sometimes internet connection is not working and when i will restart network using /etc/init.d/networking restart it works fine but in this case It sometimes restart my whole system.@Marker

Comment: Yes sometimes it reboot my whole system.Now I found this method (invoke-rc.d networking stop && invoke-rc.d networking start)@danglingpointer

Comment: NONE of these things are in my brand-new install from official sources of Debian12. It doesn't know what eth0, eth1, ifconfig, /etc/init.d/networking, or NetworkManager is. None of those exist or are understood by Debian. `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` is the single thing here that doesn't give an error message, but neither does it do anything else. My entire networking system disappeared the first time I rebooted after installing, apparently just totally uninstalled itself.  What kind of a crazy system does this?????? How are there no solutions to this ANYWHERE?